# Kubuntu partition/disk doesen't show up on Asus Zephyrus bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu

I have an Asys Zephyrus M15 GU502LW with two SSDs. My goal was to have Windows 11 on one drive and Kubuntu on another one, with secure boot running for bitlocker.

- I installed Windows 11 on the first drive
- Turned off fast boot, kept secure boot on.
- Created a Kubuntu live disk, booted from it
- Installed kubuntu on the second drive. I left the default install settings, selecting to "install proprietary drivers" and "configure secure boot" checkboxes.
- Booted into Kubuntu just fine. Both OS showed up at grub.

Today Windows asked for my bitlocker key twice. I realized that I wasn't seeing my grub menu. I booted into my bios to hard-boot into linux and the entry is missing, I only see the windows boot manager. Windows disk manager shows a 512 EFI partition and a 950gb primary partition, so the OS is still there.

- How do I restore my linux partition if I can't see it from my BIOS?
- How can I keep secure boot on, without windows bothering me for my key?
- How can I make sure this doesen't happen again? I'm worried that it was working fine yesterday

I am willing to reinstall linux one last time, but I need to make sure I won't get locked out again. Please be kind and link to step by step guides, I'm a linux user but not great when it comes to this stuff.